# What is good practice for abstracting generics?

Tags: vb.net, generics, interface, abstraction

Consider the following scenario:

```
Public Class Condition(Of T)

    '...

End Class
```

Now, I create several instances of this class with various types. I now desire to populate a generic list with these instances. Something like:

```
Dim Conditions As New List(Of Condition....?)
Conditions.add(new Condition(Of String))
Conditions.add(new Condition(Of Double))
Conditions.add(new Condition(Of CustomClass))
```

What is the best way to do this? For now I am doing the following:

```
Public Class Condition(Of T)
    implements ICondition

    '...

End Class
```

And using it like so:

```
Dim Conditions As New List(Of ICondition)
Conditions.add(new Condition(Of String))
Conditions.add(new Condition(Of Double))
Conditions.add(new Condition(Of CustomClass))
```

However, ICondition is just totally empty. Which makes me think there is probably a better or more accepted way to go about things. I could also inherit from an empty base class, would that be better? What is the preferred method of doing this kind of thing?

I understand that so long as the list that contains the generics is of a broader type that I can insert conditions of any type. However I do not want to make it any broader than necessary - I only want to be able to insert objects that are instances of `Public Class Condition(Of T)`, but whose types may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer differs, depending upon the version of the .NET Framework that you're using.  Look up articles about **covariance** and **contravariance** to understand the problem.  [Here's an example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

.NET 4 and 4.5 support this kind of usage.

Earlier versions of .NET would make you use something like the `ICondition` interface that you mention.

Comment: I'm aware that I could just make my `List(Of Condition..)` broader, into something like `List(Of Object)`, but I want to keep the type restrictions as narrow as possible - they must be instantiated from `Condition(Of T)` - but with arbitrary types. Am I not making correct implications from the article?

Comment: You may be stretching past the limits of covariance and contravariance, but I assumed your code was just a sample and not actual working code.  For covariance and/or contravariance to help you out, the types in the condition objects need to be part of the same inheritance tree.  Since string, int, and double don't cooperate that way (except that they are Objects), you only have 2 options - use Object in the list, or use ICondition in the list.

Comment: Alright, I see how this may be a rare example. The project is an interesting one ;). This has come up twice in my project so far.. but maybe it's because I'm trying to force a structure that doesn't exist naturally. Though it seems to suit the project well so I'll continue with it. Thanks.